# Referencing File in project folder using FileInputStream in Java

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to reference a txt file in my code which will read values in using the FileInputStream, but I'm not sure how to set up the path so I wont have to specifically type out "C:\...\file.txt" into the constructor. I know theres a way to do it I just cant seem to find it anywhere. The API is a little vague, couldnt quite make it out from the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've tagged this `android`. So I'll assume you're working on it.

Put that text file in your `raw` or `assets` folder of your `res` folder.

You can access those files using `getResources().openRawResource()` and `getResources().getAssets()` respectively.

Comment: Ahh I see, I didnt know I could do thatt, thanks for the help

Comment: It kind of helped, but for some reason its not building because it doesnt understand what an assets folder is